# predicateWithFormat vs stringWithFormat: is the former supposed to do the same as the latter?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an array with file names and I want to find all the names that end with e.g. *00001.trc* when `traceNum` is 1. I tried this:

```
NSPredicate *tracePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH \"%05d.trc\"", traceNum];
```

and my predicate was `SELF ENDSWITH "%05d.trc"` instead of `SELF ENDSWITH "00001.trc"`

I tried this:

```
NSPredicate *tracePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH %@%05d.trc%@", @"\"", traceNum, @"\""];
```

and I got an exception: `Unable to parse the format string "SELF ENDSWITH %@%05d.trc%@"`.

So I tried this:

```
NSPredicate *tracePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH \"%05d.trc\"", traceNum]];
```

and it works.

So do I really need `stringWithFormat` in addition to `predicateWithFormat` or is there something I'm not doing correctly in creating my predicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct; `predicateWithFormat:` is not quite the same as `stringWithFormat:`.

It's different for a couple major reasons:

1. It's not actually creating a new string.  It's just looking through the format string and seeing what the next thing to substitute is, popping that off the `va_list`, and boxing it up into the appropriate `NSExpression` object.
2. It has to support a format specifier that `NSString` doesn't: `%K`.  This is how you substitute in a key path.  If you tried to substitute in the name of a property using `%@`, it would actually be interpreted as a literal string, and not as a property name.
3. Using formatting constraints (I'm not sure what the proper term is) like the `05` in `%05d` isn't supported.  For one, it doesn't make sense.  `NSPredicate` does numerical comparisons (in which case `00005` is the same thing as `5`, and thus the zero padding is irrelevant) and string comparisons (in which you can just format the string yourself before giving it to `NSPredicate`).  (It does other comparisons, like collection operations, but I'm skipping those for now)

So, how do you do what you're trying to do?  The best way would be like this:

```
NSString *trace = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%05d.trc", traceNum];
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH %@", trace];
```

This way you can do all the formatting you want, but still use the more correct approach of passing a constant string as the predicate format.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer