# stringWithFormat: vs. predicateWithFormat:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nspredicate

When using `NSString stringWithFormat:` I like to re-use my arguments whenever possible. Like this:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1$@ = %2$@ OR (%1$@ = %2$@ AND %3$@ = %4$@)",
                  someValue, @YES,
                  anotherValue, @NO];
```

Using NSPredicate this doesn't work:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%1$K = %2$@ OR (%1$K = %2$@ AND %3$K = %4$@)",
                              someKey, @YES,
                              anotherKey, @NO];
```

What I have to do instead is:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@ OR (%K = %@ AND %K = %@)",
                              someKey, @YES,
                              someKey, @YES,
                              anotherKey, @NO];
```

I know that %K is only supported ([predicateWithFormat vs stringWithFormat: is the former supposed to do the same as the latter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238631/predicatewithformat-vs-stringwithformat-is-the-former-supposed-to-do-the-same-a)) by NSPredicate and there are some differences, but typing it twice is still ugly. Any other options?

Comment: A little bit unrelated, but what is the reason of double checking `%1$K = %2$@` in your predicate (`(A OR (A AND B))`). Either `%1$K = %2$@` would evaluate to `YES`, and second part of condition will not be evaluated at all, or it always will evaluate to `NO`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks @BorisVerebsky, I couldn't use the original code. That's a logical gap in the example. I just wanted to show the general idea.